# Run Jmeter GUI from java without local installation

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm building an application to create a JMeter Testplan based on a swagger JSON file, using JMeter api. I am able to run this testplan in non-GUI mode programmatically ( as in this question: [Run JMeter test case by a Java Stand-Alone Application, without having JMeter installed locally.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215926/run-jmeter-test-case-by-a-java-stand-alone-application-without-having-jmeter-in) )

However, I'd like to start the JMeter Gui from my Java Code, to set user defined variables (query parameters, credentials and so on) manually.

(edit: I am aware that I can set parameters without using the GUI. However, the goal is to easily edit parameters, activate/deactivate requests in the testplan and start them, using the GUI, in order to test an API using different parameters)

Is this possible without a local installation of Jmeter, if all the necessary jars are on the classpath?

My first approach was to use the classes that are used in regular Jmeter Installation, especially the NewDriver class. Unfortunately the class is final, so I cant extend it in such a fashion that the needed config and jars are loaded from the classpath.

So basically the question is:
Any chance to run Jmeter GUI from Java code without local installation of JMeter?

Comment: you don't need to start GUI for any work you listed. You can alter test plan file directly using either JMeter API, or even treating it as a normal xml file

Comment: I'm aware of that. That does not help with the issue at hand though.

Comment: I think your options are either altering JMeter code, and having your own custom build, or using one of Java/Swing test frameworks that can interact with Java GUI (https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18554/open-source-tools-for-automation-of-java-gui-application-testing). Neither option is reliable, and both have a high maintenance tag, so good luck. I would still do anything to avoid dealing with gui though